# Game creating infinite map

Tags: java, android

I want to make a never ending mobile game. The game is 2D so I randomly create the tile which fits the screen. Right now I have been using a while loop to create the map. Depending on while statement I create the size of the map. Using this method will make the map load and it will take lots of memory while playing the game on the mobile. My question is how is a better way to create an infinite map?

Below is the code for creating a map of size 100. I can make the map larger if I change while statement. But that way the map will not be infinite.

```
    // Initialize Tiles
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = 6;
        while (i < 100) {
        int n = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
        if (n == 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {

                if (j == 3) {
                    Tile t = new Tile(i, j, 2);
                    tilearray.add(t);
                }
            }
       }
```

Comment: Create the map as you go, instead of creating it all up front, and use a function of the map coordinates as a seed for the random number generator so that the map is deterministic.

Comment: Real infinity is not possible because you would need infinite memory ;) I don't know your game, but if the tiles do not always be the same for a given coordinate you could only generate tiles for the current viewport and a small area around the viewport. If the viewport changes you just generate new tiles and "release" the old ones. If you then go back to the old viewport you would generate new tiles again.

Comment: My map is always in movement. How should I check map coordinates while the tiles are moving? Where in the game loop should I create the map as I go?